# How do I set LD_PRELOAD to a process?

Tags: compiling, steam

I recently digged out some mods for a game called PAYDAY 2. It's called the Basic Lua Tool. After compiling, the `README.md` file asked me to

> set LD_PRELOAD for the PAYDAY2 process to find the loader

However I have to run PAYDAY 2 through Steam so I can't just go into the Terminal and run the process `payday2_release`. How do I force Steam to use the `payday2_release` with LD_PRELOAD? I also don't know the syntax for LD_PRELOAD so please help.

Source for the BLT (GitHub): https://github.com/blt4linux/blt4l

Loader is called `libblt_loader.so`

Comment: Here: https://github.com/blt4linux/blt4l/issues/41

Comment: Yeah just found that seconds ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. According to the file `blt4l_1.3_Ubuntu-precise-steamrt` on the website https://github.com/blt4linux/blt4l/releases/ there is already a prebuilt `libblt_loader.so` (wasted 2 weeks compiling this) and a `README.md` saying

> Move the contents of this folder in to your PAYDAY 2 folder, so that
>   it looks like this:
>
> ```
> PAYDAY 2/
>     mods/
>     libblt_loader.so
> ```
>
> Open Steam, and open the properties for PAYDAY 2. Select "Set Launch
>   Options", and set it to:
>
> ```
> env LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD ./libblt_loader.so" %command%
> ```
>
> If your PAYDAY 2 folder is in a different library folder, change the
>   path accordingly.